# In CSS, when does/should one use the `url()` function versus a string?

Tags: css, url

What's the difference between

```
.class { background-image: 'bg.png'; }
```

and

```
.class { background-image: url('bg.png'); }
```

?

Equivalently,

```
@import 'file.css';
```

vs.

```
@import url('file.css');
```

Comment: tbh I don't think it's valid to not use `url()`.

Comment: This might help. http://jeffreybarke.net/tests/paths/

Comment: the `@import` rule can be written without `url()` - it's true. But I haven't found `background-image` property without `url()`. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my testing and research, `background-image: 'bg.png';` is completely invalid. According to MDN, [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) must be defined as a keyword or an [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image) which when referencing an image file must use the `url` function.

For [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) however, the `url` function is optional and there is no difference.

---

**Invalid:**

```
.class {
    background-image: 'bg.png';
}
```

**Valid:**

```
.class {
    background-image: url('bg.png');
}
```

---

**Valid and Identical:**

```
@import 'file.css';
@import url('file.css');
```

Comment: Cool. MDN is lacking this small bit of information regarding `@import` statements.

Comment: ... And so, for consistency, it is best to use `url()` for imports as well.

Answer (score 7):

According to [MDN `<image>` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image):

> These are valid image values:
>
> ```
> url(test.jpg)                          The url() function, as long as test.jpg is an image
> linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, red)  A <gradient>
> element(#colonne3)                     A part of the page, used with the element() function, if colonne3 is an existing CSS id on the page.
> ```
>
> These are invalid image values:
>
> ```
> cervin.jpg                             An image file must be defined using the url() function.
> url(report.pdf)                        The file pointed by the url() function must be an image.
> element(#fakeid)                       If fakeid is not an existing CSS id on the page
> ```

Since the value of [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) must be one or more `<image>` (or `none`), the difference is that `background-image: url('bg.png')` is valid and `background-image: 'bg.png'` is invalid.

For `@import`, the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import) says they are equivalent:

> The '@import' keyword must be followed by the URI of the style sheet to include. A string is also allowed; it will be interpreted as if it had url(...) around it.
>
> The following lines are equivalent in meaning and illustrate both
>   '@import' syntaxes (one with "url()" and one with a bare string):
>
> ```
> @import "mystyle.css";
> @import url("mystyle.css");
> ```